# Select a class within a Id javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with id = level_1 and I have to hide all classes with class name="child" within the div with id = level_1. This is my code, but it is not working.

```
<div id="level_1">
     <div class="child">1</div>
     <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

`$("#level_1 .child").hide();`

Edit:

I want to see only the level immediately next to the clicked level contained in the clicked id.

Example, when flip_0 is clicked, I want to see only the level_2 divs contained in the id='flip_0' but not the level_2 items contained in other ids like 'flip_1' or 'flip_2'.

I have added my full code for Html and Jquery:

```
<div class="flip level_1" id="flip_0">
    Level 1.1
</div>
<div>
    <div class="flip level_2 panel" id="flip_1">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class = "panel level_3" >
        Item 1.1
    </div>
    <div class= "panel level_3">
        Item 1.2
    </div>
    <div class = "flip level_2 panel">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="flip level_3">
        Item 2.1
    </div>
    <div class="flip level_3">
        Item 2.2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flip level_1" id="flip_2">
    Level 1.2
</div>
<div class="panel level_2">
    Item 2.1
</div>
<div class="panel level_2">
    Item 2.2
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(evt)
{
  $(".flip").click(function(evt)
    {

    var class_name_parts = evt.target.className.split("_");
    var level = parseInt(class_name_parts[1]);
    alert(level);
    for( var i= (level+1); i<=3; i++)
    {
        //alert("loop " + i);
        var x= ".level_"+i;
        $(x).hide();
    }
    alert("#"+evt.target.id+" "+".level_"+(level+1));
    $("#"+evt.target.id+" .level_"+(level+1)).show();/*toggle(50);, function()
    {
        var close = "."+evt.target.id + "_to_close";
        $(close).hide();
    });*/
});
```

});

Comment: My guess is you are calling it before the elements are rendered on the page. AKA onload or document ready is needed.

Comment: Checked the console for errors? The general code itself seems fine. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TPcHk/

Comment: Just to complete epascarello's comment, you could call this code inside `$(document).ready(function() { /* here */ });`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - He wouldn't *have* to. He could also run the code anytime after those elements are created in the DOM, like at the end of the page before the closing body tag.

Comment: @j08691 Yup, bad wording, my mistake. I supposed he wanted to run it ASAP.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please look at it again.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#level_1 .child").hide();
   });
```

You're writing proper code,but may be you're hiding the content before the div is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery works only when the DOM model is ready. So its better to use jquery code after DOM creation. For that you can use `$(document).ready()` function. Write your code inside this. It will execute only when your DOM is created.